# Why is Padmé washing R2D2?

Tags: star-wars, padme

When Padmé's Naboo Cruiser escaped from the trade Federation, Padmé thanked R2D2 for saving the ship. The one thing I don't get is who is who, Padmé and her handmaid, because the Queen told one of her handmaids to wash R2, and it turns out that it's Padmé herself who is washing R2. Could someone explain this scene to me?